# [SOLVED]create a child process with STDIN and STDOUT as being piped in UTF-16

Tags: windows, visual-c++, process, pipe, utf-16

I have created a child process with the use of `CreateProcessW` function which has pipes to be as the **STDOUT** and **STDIN** between itself and its parent process. I am not able to use `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` functions to send and get back data as wide characters.

I am not aware of setting **std::locale** for pipes. Is there a way to specifically tell those pipes to encode data as wide characters in UTF-16, similar to what one uses for **ifstreams** and **ofstreams**?

Thanks.

Here you are:

```
const unsigned int sz = 1024;
static wchar_t buffer [sz];

int WriteToPipe(const std::wstring& str)
{
    int result = WriteFile(PipeStdin, (LPVOID)str.c_str(), str.size(), &bytesWritten, NULL);
    _assert(str.size()==bytesWritten);
    return  result;
}

// simply turns back what was on its stdin 
wchar_t* ReadFromPipe()
{
     ReadFile(PipeStdout, (LPVOID)buffer, sz, &bytesRead, NULL); 
     return buffer;
}   

void Test()
{
    std::wstring test  { L"test" };
    WriteToPipe (test);
    wchar_t* ret = ReadFromPipe (); // gets back 't' when using std::wcout
}
```

It gets only 't', apparently because the buffer was t \0 e \0 s \0 t \0.

If pipe's default encoding is UTF-8, it makes sense, otherwise I have to find out what is doing there. If I could set pipes to treat the buffer as UTF-16, then it would be good.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ I made some code available. Setting up HANDLEs for child's Stdin and Stdout was based on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I made two changes in my 'Preprocessor Defenitions' namely adding ***_UNICODE*** and ***_MBCS*** macros available and also adding UTF-16 mode for std::wcin as follows:

```
const unsigned long MaxCode = 0x10FFFF;
const std::codecvt_mode Mode = (std::codecvt_mode)(std::generate_header | std::little_endian);
std::locale utf16_locale(std::wcin.getloc(), new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, MaxCode, Mode>);
std::wcin.imbue (utf16_locale);
```

Answer (score 2):

WriteFile takes number of bytes to write, not number of characters.

When I replace `str.size ()` there with `sizeof (wchar_t) * str.size ()` then the whole string gets written and then read out. At least when I create the pipe with plain CreatePipe call with default parameters.

Also be sure to NUL-terminate it before passing to wprint or wout.